# Exit from a NodeJS script when all asynchronous tasks are done

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, firebase

I'm executing some asynchronous process with firebase with NodeJS.

I'd like to stop when finish all tasks the NodeJS process execution without the need of Ctrl+C command.

I tried to exit from the process, but it runs before all execution are done.

How can I do to run all asynchronous tasks and then exit from the script?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, all your asynchronous processes should be promises, then you wrap all of these promises in a single promise with `Promise.all` and exit when that promise resolves. Like this:

```
Promise.all([

 promiseForAsynchronousProcess1,
 promiseForAsynchronousProcess2,
 promiseForAsynchronousProcess3,
 ... and so on...

]).then(process.exit);
```

Comment: For anyone else that, like me, is not thinking 100% asyc yet.. I made a dumb mistake before this clued me in.  then() needs a function (process.exit) not a value (process.exit(0)).  The latter will run as soon as node rips through your promise creations and exit with extreme prejudice.