# How to exit process when script completes foreach loop

Tags: javascript, loops, process

I have a Node.js script that I have an array of objects which I do some processing on inside a `forEach` loop, I want to have it so that when the forEach loop finishes that it then runs `process.exit(0)`

I'm not sure how to do this and googling these things together doesn't seem to yield much for helpful results.

I want something like

```
let array = [] // some data here

array.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item) // place holder
}

process.exit(0)
```

Now if I do this how it is the process will exit prematurely because of Node being async. I am trying to make it behave synchronously and was not sure how I could do that. I thought about a set timeout but that will not scale with what I need it to. I will never know how long it will take because the array will almost never be the same size.

How do I get it to exit the process when the forEach is complete?

Comment: Maybe give a callback function to whatever async thing you're doing inside the loop and calling `process.exit(0);` after the callback has been called array.length times? (just a thought, still feels a bit messy)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870227/exit-from-a-nodejs-script-when-all-asynchronous-tasks-are-done

Comment: @Aamir Sorry not a duplicate as that is promise.all and dealing with promises not foreach loops, they work differently.

Comment: @JoshKirby your only choice really is to use Promises. (Note that `async` and `await` are really Promises under the hood.)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a promise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```js
const loopMyArrayPlease = (array) => { 
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    array.forEach((item) => {
        console.log(item) // place holder
        if(!item)
          reject("Unable to do the thing")
    })
    resolve(array);
  });
}

let myArray = ["One", 2, "Three"] // some data here

loopMyArrayPlease(myArray).then(arrayResult => { 
  /** Do some stuff */ 
  console.log(arrayResult)
  process.exit(0)
})
.catch(console.log)
```

Comment: Using Promises is correct, but this won't work. The root problem is that *each* array element triggers asynchronous operations.